# Detect if touch on a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a viewController that has a UIView as a subview, I was wondering how i might tell if and only if the user has clicked on the UIView from the Viewcontroller.

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the UITapGestureRecognizer documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You'll instantiate a UITapGestureRecognizer in your UIViewController, using initWithTarget:action (passing a selector which will handle your tap). Then add the UIGestureRecognizer to your UIView via the addGestureRecognizer method.

Comment: But that only involves a tap, what if the user is pressing and then dragging their finger inside the UIView, i was thinking using `touchesBegan:` but i just dont know how.

Comment: hmmm, I guess I misunderstood the question, and thought you only wanted to know about taps. There are many gesture recognizers to choose from if you wish to capture other user behaviors. I'd use touchesBegan only if you want to capture some behavior that's not covered by an existing GestureRecognizer subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded methods. Depending on the application, you could as well use touchesCancelled.

If none of these work, you might want to use UIGestureRecognizers - UIPanGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer.

Just in case it might be helpful, you can also use two gesture recognizers at the same time using the method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```